# Can I create a Windows application which uses MySQL with PHP

Tags: c#, php, mysql, .net

I want to create a Windows application which uses MySQL database with PHP. Can I create such kind of application with C#. Note :- The application i want to create should be compatible with Windows 7 and above versions it should not like a Microsoft's Store app that don't run in Windows 7.

Comment: If you want to program PHP, then only add that tag. Don't spam with unrelated language tags.

Comment: On the plus side, that makes closing easier.